# Kendo DropDownListFor Razor MVC not populating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm unable to get the ddl to populate..... I've researched for about 3 hrs.  Here is my code.  What am I doing wrong

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Ethnicity)
    .OptionLabel("--Select--")
    .DataTextField("Description")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; height:31px;" })
    .DataSource(source => {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetEthinicityValueSet", "HomeController").Type(HttpVerbs.Post); 
        }).ServerFiltering(false);
    })
    .Enable(true)
    .AutoBind(true)
)
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<DTOEthnicity> GetEthinicityValueSet()
{
    ClientDB info = new ClientDB ();
    return info.GetEthnicities();
}
```

This returns data in Quickwatch:

```
Description: "Hispanic"
Id: -2
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning json? - `public JsonResult GetEthinicityValueSet() { .... return Json(info.GetEthnicities()); }`

Comment: I changed it to this and still no dice.. i get approx 10 undefined elements... ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke does my ddl code look wrong anywhere?

Comment: It been a long time since I used Kendo, but your code looks OK.

Comment: Your kendo code looks fine. Did you check if GetEthinicityValueSet is getting proper values. Try hard-coding values and see if it works

Comment: @veenapanakanapalli it appears so.. http://imgur.com/YzgtpCM

Comment: Why is Id negative. Value are like that or it is because it is something wrong?

Comment: Purposely done as they are manually entered items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
public JsonResult GetEthinicityValueSet()
{
    ClientDB info = new ClientDB ();    
    return Json(info.GetEthnicities(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Adding the proper JsonBehavior is what did it.  Thanks so mcuch